# Create Checks with Quickbooks API

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

Please help me on writing a check using the QuickBooks online(Qbo) API. I tried to do that but i'm always getting an error saying "Error validating Detail Lines:At least one detail line is required." Sample Code is in Below.. How should I add Lines for Checks.

```
                    Dim existingChk = New Qbo.Check()
                    Dim existingChks = commonService.FindAll(existingChk, 1, 10).ToList()

                    Dim payment = New Qbo.Payment()
                    Dim payments = commonService.FindAll(payment, 1, 10).ToList()

                    Dim qboCheck = New Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.CheckHeader()
                    Dim bank = New Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Account()
                    bank.Type = Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.AccountTypeEnum.Asset
                    Dim Banks = commonService.FindAll(bank, 1, 100).ToList()
                    Dim accountId As New Qbo.IdType
                    For Each bnk As Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Account In Banks
                        If bnk.Name = "Test Bank" Then
                            accountId = bnk.Id
                        End If
                    Next
                    qboCheck.BankAccountId = accountId
                    qboCheck.BankAccountName = "Test Bank"
                    qboCheck.TotalAmt = 20.0
                    qboCheck.Currency = Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.currencyCode.USD
                    qboCheck.TxnId = payments(0).Id
                    Dim qboCustomer = New Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Customer()
                    Dim qboCustomers = commonService.FindAll(qboCustomer, 1, 10).ToList()
                    For Each cus As Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Customer In qboCustomers
                        If cus.Name.Contains("Customer1") Then
                            qboCheck.EntityId = cus.Id
                        End If
                    Next
                    qboCheck.EntityType = Qbo.EntityTypeEnum.Customer

                    Dim check = New Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Check()
                    check.Header = qboCheck
                    check.Id = New Qbo.IdType
                    check.Id.idDomain = existingChks(0).Id.idDomain
                    check.Id.Value = CInt(existingChks(0).Id.Value) + 1

                    Dim resultCheck As Qbo.Check = TryCast(commonService.Add(check), Qbo.Check)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358642/how-to-add-accountid-or-itemid-when-creating-checks-in-quickbooks?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is a bug in .net devkit(I'm not 100% sure).
JavaDocs says accountId and itemId both are inherited from LinePurchase(PFB snapshot). But in .net devkit, I don't see those fields neither in LinePurchase nor in LineBase.

JavaDoc Ref - http://developer-static.intuit.com/SDKDocs/QBV2Doc/ipp-java-devkit-2.0.10-SNAPSHOT-javadoc/

[image]

API endpoints are working fine.

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0400_quickbooks_online/check#Sample_Create_Request_XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Check xmlns:ns2="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/qbo" xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2">
    <Header>
        <TxnDate>2013-08-09</TxnDate>
        <BankAccountId>44</BankAccountId>
        <EntityId>2</EntityId>
    </Header>
    <Line>
        <Desc>Hard Disks</Desc>
        <Amount>500</Amount>
        <BillableStatus>NotBillable</BillableStatus>
        <ItemId>4</ItemId>
        <Qty>10</Qty>
        <UnitPrice>50</UnitPrice>
    </Line>
</Check>
```

PN -

`<BankAccountId>` : This account should be a 'checking' type.

`<ItemId>` : Item should have a 'ExpenseAccountRef' tag.

You can test this usecase, using ApiExplorer tool.

Link - https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V2QBO

If possible I'll try this using .net devkit on monday and confirm if it is a bug in .net devkit.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. Is this .Net Dev kit reliable to Use for our application? Is there a way to integrate to API without using this SDK?

Comment: Devkit is fine. You need to use the items array->Itemchoicetype1 enum. The ItemsElementName returns ItemsChoiceType1[]
Ref - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358642/how-to-add-accountid-or-itemid-when-creating-checks-in-quickbooks?rq=1

Endpoint detail is available in IPP docs. So, you can definitely call this API without using devkit.
You need to use some Restclient and you also need to parse the response XML. (Devkit is much easier)

Answer (score 0):

Adding pseudo code for c# for BillpaymentHeader.

Similarly you can use it for CheckLine:

```
   billheader.ItemsElementName = new ItemsChoiceType[1];
   billheader.ItemsElementName[0] = ItemsChoiceType.BankAccountId;
   billheader.Items = new object[1];
   billheader.Items[0] = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.IdType() { idDomain = Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.idDomainEnum.QBO, Value = "1" };
```

Refer- [How to add AccountID or ItemID when creating Checks in QuickBooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358642/how-to-add-accountid-or-itemid-when-creating-checks-in-quickbooks?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

If you have bill already then you can simply use billpayment API to create checks.
URL : https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/111111111111/billpayment?minorversion=4

request JSON data:

```
{
  "VendorRef": {
    "value": "1",
    "name": "vendor_name"
  },
  "PayType": "Check",
  "CheckPayment": {
    "BankAccountRef": {
      "value": "1",
      "name": "Test Account"
    }
  },
  "TotalAmt": 100.00,
  "PrivateNote": "Acct. 1JK90",
  "Line": [
    {
      "Amount": 100.00,
      "LinkedTxn": [
        {
          "TxnId": "1",
          "TxnType": "Bill"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```