# How to add AccountID or ItemID when creating Checks in QuickBooks

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

When I write checks through the Intuit .Net SDK, I'm getting the following error saying

> "Error validating Detail Line 1, Account ID or Item ID Field:Please specify an Item ID or an Account ID."

API Documentation also saying that Line (CheckLine) should have **Account ID** or **Item ID**. But there aren't any Property for **Account ID** or **Item Id** in CheckLine Object. Could you please tell me how to assign **account Id** or **Item ID** for the CheckLine object.

sample code:

```
    Dim line = New Qbo.CheckLine(1) {}
                    line(0) = New Qbo.CheckLine() With { _
                        .Amount = 20,
                        .BillableStatus = Qbo.BillableStatusEnum.NotBillable,
                        .AmountSpecified = True
                    }
```

Comment: PFB link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17342010/create-checks-with-quickbooks-api/17377822#17377822

Answer (score 0):

Please see the class library documentation for .net sdk from: 
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits 
Or use direct link: 
http://developer-static.intuit.com/SDKDocs/QBV2Doc/IntuitDataServicesSDK/

You need to use the items array->Itemchoicetype1 enum. The ItemsElementName returns ItemsChoiceType1[]
Attaching the screenshots. 
[image: Checkline]

[image: Items array]

Answer (score 0):

Adding pseudo code for c# for BillpaymentHeader.

Similarly you can use it for CheckLine:

```
   billheader.ItemsElementName = new ItemsChoiceType[1];
   billheader.ItemsElementName[0] = ItemsChoiceType.BankAccountId;
   billheader.Items = new object[1];
   billheader.Items[0] = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.IdType() { idDomain = Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.idDomainEnum.QBO, Value = "1" };
```